# Best approach for reusable swift code UIKit

Tags: swift, xcode

I cannot see a practical approach for reusable storyboard patterns in Xcode/Swift. I have a number of ViewControllers which have almost identical behavior and appearance. So the viewDidLoad() is always the same:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    labelKESumme.text = something
}
```

Because each ViewController has to be configured with its own class and Swift lacks multi inheritance I've tried to create an extension like this:

```
extension UIViewController {
  func show() {
    self.labelKESumme.text = something <== ... has no member
  }
}
```

But that doesn't work due to 'has no member' errors. Also it's not possible to configure outlets between the label and the extension code. Need an approach for configure many view controllers with same content without code duplication.

Comment: I like the comment `lacks the multi inheritance`

Answer (score 0):

You can use protocol extensions like below

```
// protocol 
protocol Showable {
   var labelKESumme: UILabel?
   func show()
}

//protocol extension if you want same functionality everywhere
extension Showable {
func show() {
      labelKESumme?.text = something
   }
}

// just conform the the protocol
ABCViewController: Showable {
}

// just conform the the protocol
XYZViewController: Showable {
}

// In some code where you have viewController as UIViewController and you know
// that this object conforms to Showable protocol then you can do like this
guard let showable = viewController as? Showable {
    return
}

showable.show()
```